# N-gram extractor

Tags: algorithm, string-algorithm

I want to solve a following algorithmic problem. Given a set of strings s1, s2, ..., sn. I want to find a string s_e, which contains all n-grams, which exist in all input string.

Consider an example with three following strings:

```
ABABC
BABCA
ABCBA
```

The n-grams are (I mark n-grams which are missing in at least one string with asterisk):

```
A B C
AB BA BC CA* CB*
ABA* BAB* ABC BCA* BCB* CBA*
ABAB* BABC* ABCA* ABCB* BCBA*
ABABC* BABCA* ABCBA*
```

So the solution should contain n-grams: "A", "B", "C", "AB", "BA", "BC", "ABC". Thus the shortest such string is "BABC". It contains an n-gram, which does not exist in all input strings, namely "BABC", but that's OK.

And the resulting string I called n-gram extractor, because by iterating through all n-grams of the result you can get all n-grams, which are present in all of the input strings.

If this is a know problem, I would be happy to know a name for it. (was: I thought I have an idea for a solution, but turned out I don't).

For the input it is safe to assume that square of the size of the alphabet (n^2) is smaller than the length of the shortest string.

Comment: Please, have a look at *De Bruijn graph*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph

Comment: Are you looking for help with the algorithm or do you just want to know if it exists? I think that it might be important to note that the resulting function doesn't need 'all' n-grams to get the correct results. It just needs the maximal n-grams, or the n-grams that are not substrings of any other proper n-grams. For instance, since your example has "ABC" as an n-gram, you don't really need to consider 'A', 'B', 'C', 'AB', or 'BC' when making that final string. This will greatly lighten the load on the algorithm.

Comment: @OwenCummings I wanted to know if the algorithm exists, and use it if it does. You're right that having maximal n-grams as target is sufficient, but the resulting algorithm should be equivalent.

Comment: I just realized that actually the shortest input string is a viable answer, because by definition it contains all the n-grams which are present in all other strings, with an exception that it way contain actually more n-grams. So I'm curious if there is a solution with the shortest possible string.